# MTG - What is the set "Oversize Cards"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

On tcgplayer.com (can anyone verify they are legit? Never bought anything from them. Might as well ask) there is a planeswalker for sale that is from the set "Oversize cards" (picture below). There are other planeswalkers for sale with the name being "Name (Oversize)".

Is the below pictured card actually different in size or any other aspect than a normal Planeswalker?

[image]

Comment: There is a very high chance the card is from a promo for stores. I saw that garruk a while ago as oversized card in my local store. It was about 1m high. Good for showing customers but terrible to shuffle in your deck.

Comment: Did you mean TCGPlayer? MTGPlayer.com sends me to a landing page filled with ads

Comment: Tcgplayer. Yes sorry my bad... Will edit

Comment: The Garruk you referenced is from the M14 or M15 (I forget which) Pre-Release events.  You got one if you participated in the Pre-Release.  I forget what you actually did with him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oversized cards are bigger than normal Magic cards and are usually twice the size (the size of two regular Magic cards side to side.) Here you see a size comparison:

[image: example oversized card with regular size Magic card comparison]

These oversized cards are not legal for tournament play and are mostly decorative.

Comment: I thought the card was used for the Command Zone? Would that not make it legal to have on the table in Tournaments?

Comment: You can use it to mark your Commander Zone, but it is still just a decoration, much like a player mat would be. It is still not legal to play these cards during a tournament (they would be kind of obvious in your deck and would count as a marked card).

Comment: @ThunderToes Consider the scenario where your commander is returned to your hand or shuffled into your deck, and you opted to let that happen instead of returning your commander to your command zone: at that point you need a regular-sized card. But you can totally use the super-sized cards to represent your commander while it's out on the battlefield or in the command zone; in fact that's the scenario the oversized cards were made for.

Comment: Oh by legal you meant in the deck... that much was obvious to me. I thought the answer stated it was not legal to have them at tournaments. As in not even on the table.

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of cards that are larger than normal. They're mainly for show since they're not legal or practical in most formats. However a few do have "practical" uses - here are some examples:

- The particular card you reference, Garruk the Slayer, was created for the Magic 2015 prerelease and is used in a variant where one player plays normally and the other [plays as Garruk](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/win-ultimate-trophy-2014-06-23). In that variant the Garruk card starts face up and never leaves the table, so it doesn't hurt that it's oversized.
- In the casual Commander variant, you can use an oversize card as your commander - a commander starts the game face up on the table and tends to stay that way, so as above it doesn't hurt that it's oversized.

"Oversize cards" is **not** a "set" by the usual Magic definition, but I'd guess your online store categorizes them that way to make it clearer to customers they're buying an abnormal card.